# How to get and set the application name in grails 3

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, grails-3.1

I am making an application in Grails 3 and need to know , first , how to set the name of the application and secondly, how to get the name of the application within a service . I think it has to be defined in the build.gradle file, but I have not found how. I tested with the following options:

```
app.name="mediacion"
```

and the second option was:

```
appName="mediacion"
```

But neither works. I also need to get the name of the application in a service. I've done as follows :

```
GrailsApplication grailsApplication
def nombreApp = grailsApplication.metadata.'app.name'
```

The "nombreApp" variable is always null. Probably because I did not properly define the application name in build.gradle , or because the code for the name is wrong too. Any idea how I should set and get the name of the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your configuration file (application.groovy or application.yml), set the value: `appName="mediacion"`

Then, on the grails service you can reference that config value as follows:

`GrailsApplication grailsApplication
def nombreApp = grailsApplication.config.getProperty('appName')`

This is explained on the grails [doc](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html)